# Maven settings.xml releases updatePolicy

Tags: maven-2, dependency-management

in my project, I want to re-download release pom every time(like -U in snapshot) so I configed settings.xml repositories/repository/releases/updatePolicy as always, bug I found it's useless, I have to delete localRepository every time. if has a way can be done, or it is impossibility(why sttings.xml can configure releases/updatePolicy)

Comment: Why would you like to download your releases over and over again?

Comment: I want to avoid edit pom.xml procedure,  It's so terrible to update version frequently

Comment: To be honest I don't understand that. In your pom you define the versions (releases) you would like to use. If you change the version that is recorded in the pom file (via your version control). The update policy is something completely different thing and does not make sense for a release repository only for SNAPSHOT's which are something different...

Comment: there were two releases in my settings.xml,someone set updatePolicy is alway, and the other one is never. so it simplify the pom.xml's update. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT->1.0.0->1.0.1-SNAPSHOT->1.0.1 became 1.0.0->1.0.1->1.0.2. coursely, it is depend on updatePolicy in releases that was availability